# Lisp - write to file using low memory footprint

Tags: file, memory, lisp, common-lisp

I have large hash tables that I am writing to disk as an occasional backup.  I am finding that as I map the hash tables and write to a file, the RAM usage skyrockets compared to the size of the hash.

I am running lisp on emacs with slime and sbcl 2.0.3.176.  System is Ubuntu 19.10 on a dell server.

Data is multiple levels of hash tables.  The basic structure of it is:

customer-ht - hash table of structs called customer, keyed on lists of integers, like (1 2), (1 3)

```
(defstruct customer
  (var1 0)
  (var2 (make-hash-table))
  (var3 (make-hash-table)))
```

var2 hash table is simple key/value where keys are integers 1, 2, etc and value is always 'T

var3 hash table has keys that are integers and its value is another hash table where keys are lists of integers (1 2 3) (1 5 7) and value is always 'T

So, customer (1 2) has

- var1 = 5,
- var2 = hash table of key 3, value 'T
- var3 = hash table of key 9, value = hash table of key (5 6 7), value 'T

I'm using this to map and write to file:

```
(defun write-cust-to-file (filename)
  (with-open-file (s filename
                    :direction :output
                    :if-exists :supersede)
    (maphash
      #'(lambda (cust-key cust-data)
          (format s "~A ~A~%" cust-key customer-var1)
          (maphash
           #'(lambda (k1 v1)
               (declare (ignore v1))
               (format s "~A ~A~%" cust-key k1))
           (customer-var2 cust-data))
          (maphash
           #'(lambda (k1 v1)
               (maphash
                #'(lambda (k2 v2)
                    (declare (ignore v2))
                    (format s "~A ~A~%" (list cust-key "X" k1) k2))
                v1))
           (customer-var3 cust-data)))
      customer-ht))
  nil)
```

There are more vars in the struct, like these, that are all written using same maphash/write code.  So, each customer struct is quite large.

When I run this, my RAM explodes.  All my data in RAM is around 20GB.  When I run this, it goes to 40GB+.  I'm starting to think that the maphashes are duplicating data from the structs as they run.  If I run a similar write function to the maphash section above that uses k1 and k2 (2 nested mappings) on a hash that doesn't have a struct, no memory increase occurs.

Is there a way to write to file in LISP that doesn't use any extra RAM (or at least very little)?  I'll take a performance hit to save my RAM.

Additional info:  I ran dstat while running this and found that writing to disk is not continuous.  It writes a large block (20MB-120MB) about every 30 seconds, with small 12K writes every 5 seconds or so.  Also, RAM usage tops out before the function completes writing.  So, is the data being stored somewhere while waiting to write to disk?  Or is it just allocating some memory? Running (gc :full 'T) afterword recovers all the extra RAM.

Comment: It's with every problem report: please provide details. LISP could be any of a hundred implementations, the operating system is not mentioned, there are no reproducible examples...

Comment: @Mark: yes, this is better I think. Thank you.  My original comment is gone as it makes no sense now.

Comment: Your code allocates `lambda` closures, and also `(list cust-key "X" k1)`.

Comment: @Kaz: but those should (should...) all be fairly ephemeral I think, so the GC should pick them up, shouldn't it?

Comment: @tfb It does! In the question, OP writes "Running (gc :full 'T) afterword recovers all the extra RAM."

Comment: @Kaz - GC does recover it, but my issue is how to prevent (or at least minimize) the greater than doubling of RAM usage while it's writing to disk.  Right now, once I pass 50% of my RAM, I can't write to disk anymore without running out of RAM before it's done writing.  Also, I have run this as `(format s "~A ~A ~A ~A~%" cust-key "X" k1 k2)` and get the same amount of RAM usage.

Comment: I suspect this is not a question which can be answered definitively without understanding details of what's happening, but turning on the GC logging in SBCL and/or asking it explicitly how much memory it's used at controlled points (see [manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Garbage-Collection) may help debug it.

Comment: I am thinking that `format` formats a same `cust-key` a lot of times (for each of the sub-item in the sub-hashtables) - it seems wasteful. How about store the formatted string in a value before all other `maphash` and use the string after? The same can go with the `k1` of `var3`, but to a lesser extent.

Comment: Still, the bigger problem might be the GC not collecting all those garbage. But I think with this change, you should have much less garbage produced. On the other hand, I do not have an environment to test it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer.  I think that whatever is causing the leakage is SBCL-specific, so probably your best bet is to find out where the SBCL people hang out (assuming it's not here) and ask them.

However one thing to do would be to instrument the GC to see if you can work out what's going on.  You can do this by, for instance:

```
(defun dribble-gc-info ()
  (format *debug-io* "~&GC: ~D bytes consed~%"
          (sb-ext:get-bytes-consed)))

(defun hook-gc (&optional (log-file nil))
  (pushnew 'dribble-gc-info sb-ext:*after-gc-hooks*)
  (when log-file
    (setf (sb-ext:gc-logfile) log-file)))

(defun unhook-gc ()
  (setf sb-ext:*after-gc-hooks*
        (delete 'dribble-gc-info sb-ext:*after-gc-hooks*))
  (if (sb-ext:gc-logfile)
      (prog1 (sb-ext:gc-logfile)
        (setf (sb-ext:gc-logfile) nil))
      nil))
```

Then `(hook-gc "/tmp/x.out")` will cause it to both tell you when GCs run and how much memory has been consumed in total, and write copious information to `/tmp/x.out`.  It may be that this would at least give you a start in working out what's happening.

Another thing which just conceivably might help would be to insert occasional calls to `force-output` on the stream you're writing to: it's possible (but I think unlikely) that some weird buffering is going on which is causing it to make bad decisions about how big the lisp-side buffer for the file should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try `loop` to loop over the hash-tables.

sth like:

```
(loop for k1 
      being the hash-key 
      using (hash-value v1) of (customer-var1 cust-data)
      do (format s "~A ~A~%" k1 v1))
```

Or if you don't need the values:

```
(loop for k being the hash-key of (customer-var2 cust-data)
      do (format <whatever you need...>))
```

Originally I thought `maphash` would collect values but it does not, as @tfb pointed out. Then I don't know.

Comment: `maphash` doesn't collect values: see [CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_maphas.htm).